# MARS MIPS Simulator jar file keeps opening with IntelliJ IDE and it's not working

Tags: assembly, intellij-idea, mips, mars-simulator

I need to use MARS MIPS for a course but the downloaded jar file isn't opening. First it defaulted to opening with IntelliJ IDE, then Notebook, and all other programs except how it's supposed to run. I've tried to reset it, re-download it, and downloading the JDK recommended for the latest version. I was able to run it just fine on the university computers but I would like to be able to work on labs and projects from my home. Has anyone encountered this problem before that can please offer some guidance on how to get it running?

Comment: Try command line: java -jar MARS4_5.jar

Comment: When I wrote this in the command line, this is the message that I received: 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: If `java` isn't in your default `PATH` (maybe you're on Windows?) then you might need to specify the full path to a normal `java` executable from a normal JRE like OpenJDK or Oracle.  You don't need a Java *development* Kit, just the runtime.

Comment: You are correct. The java version I was using was outdated so I installed the latest version and changed the PATH variable. Now Mars MIPS crashes without opening.

Comment: Update: 

Peter Cordes was correct when saying that java wasn't my default PATH. I got the latest JDK version, because I didn't have it before, and installed it/configured path. Thank you Peter! 

After installing and configuring path (previous step), when I choose the file by clicking it, it crashed without opening. I was able to open it by going into Windows Powershell and accessing the Downloads folder. Afterwards, I put the command java -jar MARS4_5.jar (as Erik Eidt suggested) and it opened! Thank you Erik!